# LEFT OUTER JOIN problems

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, left-join

I have a error I relay cant understand, if some one could explain to me the problem as its preventing me from progressing with my program.

**the error is saying i have a syntax error on the JOIN**

**Code**

```
using (OleDbDataAdapter query_prof = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT aspnet_Users.AplicationId, aspnet_User.UserName, aspnet_User.LastActivityDate FROM (aspnet_Users LEFT OUTER JOIN UserProfile ON aspnet_User.UserName = UserProfile.UserName) WHERE (UserProfile.UserName IS NULL)", conn))
{
    query_prof.Fill(dt);
}
```

Comment: remove the brackets from the FROM expression

Comment: You have aspnet_Users in the join statement and aspnet_User in the on clause.

Comment: Why using parenthesis in a simple From clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave out the parenthesis from the from clauses:

```
FROM (aspnet_Users LEFT OUTER JOIN UserProfile ON aspnet_User.UserName = UserProfile.UserName)
```

you should do :

```
FROM aspnet_Users LEFT OUTER JOIN UserProfile ON aspnet_User.UserName = UserProfile.UserName
```

Comment: There is also the typo in `aspnet_Users` vs `aspnet_User` as mentionned by @NickZimmerman in the comments